# after postgres upgrade to v11.11(AWS), this query is causing cpu 99.9% peak. There was no such issue with v10. What is causing?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

I do realize the sql (esp. subquery) could be enhanced. But, the point is the exact query didn't have any issue in v10.11.

The subquery itself returns only 1 distinct id. If I type that in directly, the query runs in subseconds. This subquery with 'in' clause seems to be the culprit.

```
  SELECT  * 
     FROM "nego"."quotenego" AS "ModelA"
     WHERE "ModelA"."quotenegoheaderid" = 5714 AND 
     "ModelA"."qpnid" IN (
          *select distinct qpnid FROM "nego"."quotenego" AS "ModelA" 
         where 
             (("ModelA"."partnumber1" ILIKE 'a%') AND 
             ("ModelA"."partnumber2" ILIKE 'b%')) AND 
             "ModelA"."quotenegoheaderid" = 5714 AND 
             "ModelA"."mfgid" in (2598,2024)*  
     )  
     ORDER BY "ModelA"."seq" ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;
```

Any idea, why v11 is not doing this well?

Comment: Not without seeing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` outputfor both cases.

Comment: Stats don't migrate.  Did you analyze the system after the upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jjanes was right.

After running Analyze , it is now working fine.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.MajorVersion